# Volume via Jacobi fields: Proof of Lemma 5.4 of Sakai's book "Riemannian Geometry"

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

I am self-teaching Riemannian geometry and am stuck with the proof of Lemma 5.4 on page 65 of Takashi Sakai's book "Riemannian Geometry". The lines where I am stuck with are highlighted in the attached picture. In the picture, the $$\Vert \cdot \Vert$$ denotes the (absolute value of the signed) volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors it embraces (and so please ignore the wedge $\wedge$ operator. For example, $\Vert v \wedge w \Vert$ for two m-dimensional vectors $v$ and $w$ is the (absolute value of the signed) area of the parallelogram spanned by $v$ and $w$).

I got why there is factor $t^{1-m}$ there but did not get why $$\Vert Y_{1}(t) \wedge \cdots \wedge Y_{m-1}(t)\wedge \dot{\gamma}(t)\Vert = \Vert Y_{1}(t) \wedge \cdots \wedge Y_{m-1}(t)\Vert,$$ where $\gamma_{u}(t)$ is a unit speed geodesic with initial speed vector $u=e_m$ (when $t=0$). Note that the Jacobi fields are not necessarily orthogonal along $\gamma_u(t)$.

I am not able to see how $\dot{\gamma}(t)$ and $\Vert \dot{\gamma}(t) \Vert \equiv 1$ plays their roles in the height-times-base formula for the above identity. Could someone please explain why the above identity is true? Any help or hint is appreciated.

**Added:** I think I got it. By Gauss Lemma, $\dot{\gamma}_u(t)$ is orthogonal to each $Y_{i}(t)$ for $i=1,\cdots,m-1$. Since $\Vert \dot{\gamma}(t) \Vert \equiv 1$, the height of the parallelepiped is $1$. So, the base area, $\Vert Y_{1}(t) \wedge \cdots \wedge Y_{m-1}(t)\Vert$, equals the volume.

[image]

Comment: This is because $Y_i(t)$ are orthogonal to $\gamma'(t)$ if the initial data $Y_i(0)$ and $Y_i'(0)$ are orthogonal to $\gamma'(0)$. In polar coordinates, the inital data are orthogonal: by definition, $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is an "o.n.b which stands for orthonormal basis.

Comment: @DIdier_: thank you for your comment. I had realized this before your comment and edited the question. However, there is no need for the use of polar coordinates.

Comment: I made an answer with more details and added an explication using determinants to show why the norm of the wedge products split in two norms. Also, you say that there is no need for polar coordinates. I don't understand what you mean because your question is exactly to explain how the metric splits in polar coordinates. Of course, I mean riemannian polar coordinates thanks to the exponential map.

Comment: @DIdier_: there is no need for the use of polar coordinates in the sense of Riemannian geometry because (in the settings of the lemma) the determinant of the exponential map at a given point is the determinant of the matrix of coefficients of the pushed-forward tangent vectors when they are represented via the original basis, and then the height-times-base formula comes into play since this determinant is the volume of the corresponding  parallelogram. What I meant to say implicitly was "for teaching purposes, the simpler the method and the more intuition conveyed, the better".

Comment: I see. But saying that $Y_i(t)$ are orthogonal to $\gamma'(t)$ is exactly saying we are using riemannian polar coordinates because we use the fundamental idea that along a geodesic, the ambiant tangent space splits in two radically different subspaces: its own tangent space and its orthogonal. Which, in my opinion, is the most intuitive way to understand these properties of the exponential map.

Comment: @DIdier_: well said and agreed with! You have pointed out a general fact that I had overlooked. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ is a unit tangent vector to $p \in M$, then $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(tu)$ is a unit speed geodesic. If $v \in T_pM$ is orthogonal to $u$, the Gauss lemma shows that
$$
g_{\gamma(t)}\left(\mathrm{d}\exp_p(tu)\cdot u, \mathrm{d}\exp_p(tu)\cdot v\right) = g_p(u,v)
$$
and then, $\mathrm{d}\exp_p(tu)\cdot v$ is orthogonal to $\mathrm{d}\exp_p(tu)\cdot u = \gamma'(t)$.

If $Y_i(t) = t\mathrm{d}\exp_p(tu)\cdot e_i$, then $Y_i(t)$ is colinear to $\mathrm{d}\exp_p(tu)e_i$, and if $e_i$ is orthogonal to $u$, then $Y_i(t)$ is orthogonal to $\gamma'(t)$. thus, if $Y_1(t),\ldots,Y_{m-1}(t)$ are all orthogonal to $\gamma'(t)$, one has
\begin{align}
\left\|Y_1(t)\wedge\cdots\wedge Y_{m-1}(t)\wedge \gamma'(t) \right\| &= \left\| Y_1(t) \wedge \cdots \wedge Y_{m-1}(t)\right\| \left\|\gamma'(t) \right\| \\
&= \left\| Y_1(t) \wedge \cdots \wedge Y_{m-1}(t)\right\|
\end{align}
because $\gamma$ has unit speed.

The first equality may seem a bit obscur. Here is a reason why. If $(e_1,\ldots,e_{m-1},u)$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$, one can transport it as a parallel frame along $\gamma(t)$, say $(E_1(t),\ldots,E_{m-1}(t),\gamma'(t))$. It is an orthonormal basis of $T_{\gamma(t)}M$. The norm $\|Y_1(t)\wedge \cdots \wedge Y_{m-1}(t) \wedge \gamma'(t)\|$ is the absolute value of the determinant $\det\left(Y_1(t),\ldots,Y_{m-1}(t),\gamma'(t)\right)$ in any orthonormal basis. Thus, in the orthonormal basis $E_1(t),\ldots,E_{m-1}(t),\gamma'(t)$, this determinant have the form
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
g(Y_1(t),E_1(t)) & \cdots & g(Y_{m-1}(t),E_{1}(t)) & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \vdots & 0 \\
g(Y_1(t),E_{m-1}(t)) & \cdots & g(Y_{m-1}(t),E_{m-1}(t))\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \|\gamma'(t)\|
\end{vmatrix}
$$
and the formula is thus straightforward.

In the proof you are showing, the author takes $(e_1,\ldots,e_{m-1},u)$ to be and orthonormal basis. Thus, it is clear that $e_i$ and $u$ are orthogonal.

**Remark:** You can prove that $Y_i$ are all orthogonal to $\gamma'$ without the Gauss lemma, if you know that $V_i(t)=\mathrm{d}\exp_p(tu)\cdot e_i$ are Jacobi fields. Knowing they are Jacobi fields, they satisfy
$$
V_i'' = -R(\gamma',V_i)\gamma'
$$
Let $f(t) = g_{\gamma(t)}\left(V_i(t),\gamma'(t)\right)$. It is a smooth function, and one easily shows that
$$
f''(t) = g_{\gamma(t)}\left( V_i''(t),\gamma'(t)\right) = -R\left(\gamma'(t),V_i(t),\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)\right) = 0
$$
the last equality being a direct consequence of the fact that the Riemann tensor is skew symmetric in the two last variable. Thus, $f$ is an affine function, of the form $f(t) = f'(0)t + f(0)$. The initial data saying that $V_i(0)$ and $V'_i(0)$ are orthogonal to $\gamma'(0)$ show that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, thus $f=0$ and $V_i$ is orthogonal to $\gamma'(t)$.

**Comment:** there is a general use of these expressions for studying the volume outside a submanifold in a riemannian manifold. They are named Heintze-Kärcher equalities / inequalities, named after Heintze and Kärcher. You can find online (for example [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1978_4_11_4_451_0.pdf)) how they seemed to have first appeared.

Comment: thank you a lot for providing a 2nd proof on the orthogonality. I was reading Proposition 10.7 of Lee's book "An introduction to Riemannian manifolds" before stackexchange notified me of your comments. Also, thank you for providing the reference. I am at the start of seriously learning comparison techniques.

Comment: DIdier_: excellent explanations; I love them! Thank you.

Comment: How is $\| Y_1(t) \wedge \dots Y_{m-1} \wedge \gamma'(t) \|$ the absolute value of the determinant $\mathrm{det}(Y_1(t) \wedge \dots Y_{m-1} \wedge \gamma'(t))$ in any orthonormal basis? Isn't there a square root somewhere?